# Tomcat 8, axis2 webservices aar, spring jndi not bound in context

Tags: windows, spring, jndi, apache-axis, tomcat8

I have been working on an issue where JNDI name is not found in the context an axis2 webservice is running. This issue is only in Tomcat 8 when I use spring. 
Some details: (I will provide the elements that are relevant)
1. services.xml

```
<service name="ScoreService" class="com.bpl.ws.service.ScoreServiceInitializer">
<description>Simple test service</description>
<parameter name="ServiceObjectSupplier" locked="false">org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.SpringAppContextAwareObjectSupplier</parameter>
<parameter name="SpringBeanName" locked="false">scoreService</parameter>
```

2. server.xml:

```
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" xmlBase="C:\Applications\apache-tomcat-8.0.30-windows-x64\context"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

3. Context.xml

   ```
       <JarResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet"
              base="C:\Applications\apache-tomcat-8.0.30-windows-x64\commonLib" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
   ```

4.JNDI resource in the context file:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ADS" auth="Container"
  factory="com.bpl.ws.EncryptedJdbcDataSourceFactory"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
  url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxx.com:3203/xxxx"
  username="xxxxx"
  password="xxxx"
  initialSize="10"
  logAbandoned="false"
  maxActive="20"
  maxIdle="10"
  maxWait="10000"
  removeAbandoned="true"
  removeAbandonedTimeout="120"
  jdbcInterceptors="QueryTimeoutInterceptor(queryTimeout=10)"
  testOnBorrow="true"
  validationInterval="30000"
  validationQuery="Select 1 from dual"/>
```

As shown in services.xml file listing, I am using an initializer class and the code to load the spring context looks like this:
4.ScoreSerivceInitializer

```
public void startUp(ConfigurationContext ignore, AxisService service) {
    System.out.println("SCORESERVICE:: Starting up..");
    DataSource ds;


        ClassLoader cloader = service.getClassLoader();
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cloader);
        System.out.println("SCORESERVICE:: spring context starting up");
        spContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"DST-Context.xml"},false);
        spContext.setClassLoader(cloader);


        try {
            spContext.refresh();
```

5. spring context.xml (DST-Context.xml)

The DST-Context.xml entry looks like this:

```
<bean id="applicationContext"
    class="org.apache.axis2.extensions.spring.receivers.ApplicationContextHolder" />

<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/ADS</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

6. Tomcat log:

   [WARN] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in class path resource [DST-Context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/ADS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasource' defined in class path resource [DST-Context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException:
   Name [java:comp/env/jdbc/ADS] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java:comp].

Without changing anything in the configuration, if I changed the ScoreServiceInitializer to do this:

```
initCtx = new InitialContext();

        envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env"); 

        ds = (DataSource)
                  envCtx.lookup("jdbc/ADS");
```

Everything works. As you see here I don't use any spring and the jndi datasource is in context.

If I deploy the code with spring config in Tomcat 7, it works fine.
The spring context seems to be the issue but have been looking at it for a while and cant seem to figure out why Tomcat 8 has a different behavior compared to Tomcat 7. I know that Tomcat8 has changed some behavior in terms of how the Resources are configured and the dbcp is now dbcp2 and I have updated config files accordingly. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if any other info is required.

Comment: This issue is only on windows environment. The same aar and the same setup works on a unix environment.

Comment: Potentially silly question: why are you playing games with the `ClassLoader`s?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz: I am assuming this question is because of these 2 lines : ClassLoader cloader = service.getClassLoader();
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cloader);                                                                                                    If I didn't do this, Spring wouldn't be able to find the applicationcontext file that is packaged in the aar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webapp won't run uder Tomcat 8.0.23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925700/webapp-wont-run-uder-tomcat-8-0-23)

Comment: Exact same problem with axis2 1.5.1, upgrading to axis2 1.6.1 throws `NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware`

Answer (score -1):

@bplso I had the same issue when I upgrade tomcat7 to tomcat8.5 on a axis2 project, try the steps given in image. It may be solve your issue.
!

```
Step 1: Specify the connection resource in server.xml inside <GlobalNamingResources> like 
<Resource name="jdbc/name" 
global="jdbc/name" 
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
username="xxx" 
password="YYY" 
driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver" 
url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://host:port/dbname" 
maxTotal="10" 
maxIdle="10" 
maxWaitMillis="10000" /> 


Step 2: Specify the resource reference in web.xml inside the <web-app> like 

<resource-ref> 
<description> This is a reference to the global Resource for SQL database connetion. </description> 
<res-ref-name>jdbc/name</res-ref-name> 
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type> 
<res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
</resource-ref> 


Step 3: Create a context.xml file and paste it in your project/META-INF/ path as below 

<?xml version=.1.0 encoding="UTF-8.?> 
<Context> 
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/name" global="jdbc/name" type="javax.sgl.DataSource" 
</Context>
```